# Saving file path in database using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have an entity and one of its fields holds an image. How should I map/annotate this field if I want to save the image on file system and path to it in the database? Is there a way to configure Spring Data JPA to retrieve images (or files in general) from file system automatically based on paths in database?

Comment: I don't think you can configure Spring Data JPA to do that. But what possible is that you can store the image file as bytes in database and retrieve the same.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want to do it the way I mentioned.

Comment: Spring Data JPA is only meant to communicate with db, not for file system. You must code to retrieve the file from the path you get from db using Spring. That's the only way I can think of.